# getelementbyId() for div ID inside playbuzz embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a problem retrieving the value inside of a div id inside of a Playbuzz quiz embedded into my site. The div value I need to search for is "final_result_score_text". Below is the embed code for the quiz:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.playbuzz.com/widget/feed.js"></script>

<div class="pb_feed" data-embed-by="1e4cfb3b-67db-4b61-816b-27369bd25751" data-game="/nathanj15/test-quiz" data-recommend="false" data-game-info="false" data-comments="false" data-shares="false" ></div>
```

And below is the code in which I am using to try and retrieve the value.

```
document.write(document.getElementById('pb_feed').contentWindow.document.getElementById('final_result_score_text'));
```

I would appreciate any guidance on my issue.

Comment: What does the JS console say when you run that code?

Comment: Presumably Playbuzz inserts an iframe inside the div? You'll need to get `contentWindow` of the iframe, not of the containing div.

Comment: ``div``s don't have a ``contentWindow`` property, and ``pb_feed`` is a ``class``, not an ``id``.

Comment: If this does inject an iframe, and it's on a different domain, you're going to run into cross domain security issues as well.

Answer (score -1):

one issue you will have is that you want to use getelementbyId but you do not have that ID, you have a class instead so you need to change your class to

```
<div id="pb_feed" data-embed-by="1e4cfb3b-67db-4b61-816b-27369bd25751" data-game="/nathanj15/test-quiz" data-recommend="false" data-game-info="false" data-comments="false" data-shares="false" ></div>
```

Then you may have the issue as well with getElementById('final_result_score_text') where you have a class and not an ID.